# Computing the Content Length of a Multipart form Post

Tags: go

I'm trying to upload a file without loading it into memory, as shown below. Services like S3 need a `Content-Length` set in such cases. Is there a go-lang built-in to do that, or do I have to compute it myself.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func newfileUploadRequest(uri string, params map[string]string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, chan error, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    bodyReader, bodyWriter := io.Pipe()
    multiWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyWriter)
    errChan := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        defer bodyWriter.Close()
        defer file.Close()
        part, err := multiWriter.CreateFormFile(paramName, filepath.Base(path))
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        if _, err := io.Copy(part, file); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        for k, v := range params {
            if err := multiWriter.WriteField(k, v); err != nil {
                errChan <- err
                return
            }
        }
        errChan <- multiWriter.Close()
    }()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, bodyReader)
    return req, errChan, err
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note, just the file length wouldn't work as the body could have additional params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [the docs for http.Request.Write](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) it states

> If Body is present, Content-Length is <= 0 and TransferEncoding hasn't
>   been set to "identity", Write adds "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" to the
>   header

Which means if you don't set a `Content-Length`, `http.Request.Write` will use [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). This was added to `HTTP/1.1` to get rid of the need to calculate the `Content-Length` for streaming transfers just like this.

So normally Go programs use chunked encoding and there is no need to set `Content-Length`. Any modern HTTP stack should support chunked transfer encoding.

However [S3 does not support chunked transfer encoding](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#14), so I think you'll have to calculate `Content-Length` yourself.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. As a convenience, I've ended you using a small wrapper package to calculate the ContentLength of multi-part responses - https://github.com/technoweenie/multipartstreamer